# Optimized Wordpress Top Scroller Error Message: Warning: Parameter 2 to wp_hide_post_Public::query_posts_join()

Tags: wordpress, host

This error message just started hovering on the top bar of my Wordpress website

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to wp_hide_post_Public::query_posts_join() expected
to be a reference, value given in 
/home3/wabc540aavj6/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Deffbridges.org 

Hosted by HostGator
```

I'd be happy to provide any more information.

Comment: You did not ask a question?  What do you need help with?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to remove that error message from my website. I have a very, very basic understanding of how coding works.

Comment: Did you get that solved?